# .htaccess is causing infinite loop when used from subfolder, works fine in domain root

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am using this .htaccess code for PHP application.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(login|logout|public)($|/.*$) [NC]
RewriteRule . index.php [L,QSA]


RewriteRule ^login login.php?$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^logout logout.php?$1 [L]
```

If i use it within domain root `www.website.com` then it works fine but if i use it in a folder `www.website.com/app` it causes infinite loop.,

Any ideas on what i am doing wrong here?

Also, Is there a way to remove `websitename.com` in given .htaccess and make it completely dynamic so it works as it's supposed to without me entering the domain name manually for every different website.

```
RewriteEngine on 

RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?websitename.com/ [NC] 
RewriteRule \.(jpe?g|gif|bmp|png|txt|pdf|zip|rar|psd|doc|docx|xml|csv)$ - [F,NC]
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem is **not using end of line anchor `$`** in following 2 rules:

```
RewriteRule ^login login.php?$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^logout logout.php?$1 [L]
```

This is causing infinite loops since source URI `/login` and target `/login.php` are both matching regex: `^login`

Replace your rules with these:

```
RewriteRule ^login/?$ login.php?$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^logout/?$ logout.php?$1 [L]
```

Comment: Still same error, Anyways i am going through htaccess tutorials/documentation and i am sure i will find a solution soon.